# How can i redirect my xxxx.NL website to xxxx.COM website with .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web, redirect

We want to change our .nl domain to .com

I have a website with ending with .nl. I want to redirect everything to .com.
So for example, if someone visits "crossborderevent.nl/about-us" they will be redirected to "crossborderevent.com/about-us".

Does someone know how to achieve this with .htaccess file?

I've tried the following code but its not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^crossborderevent.nl [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.crossborderevent.nl
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.crossborderevent.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This rule redirects every request from example.nl to example.com